# HTTP request constantly returns 500 error, suspect header fields are responsible

Tags: http

I'm working on a HTTP file upload client, but I can't seem to get it to work. We have a test program that sends the MyImage.JPG file to the server and it works, the server uploads it and saves it in the right folder. We have another program that will display all post requests that it receives, or at least the body portion.

My client was constantly getting a 500 error, our server says: "Fail: End of stream: Class at 1085834" where the number is the length of the request. I decided to just copy and paste the request body from the test client into fiddler and see if that would work. It doesn't. It's getting the exact same error, which tells me something must be wrong in my header because the body is a copy / paste from the receiving end of the test upload program.

Here's the header

```
POST http://192.168.0.76/SSP.Upload HTTP/1.0
Host: 192.168.0.76
Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=----------032612102926055
Content-Length: <length here>
```

The rest of the request along with the test upload, show post, and MyImage.JPG are all uploaded [here](http://singularity-id.com/PostRequest.zip). If anyone has any suggestions, that would be great. We can't move away from base64, because the guy that wrote the server doesn't have support for binary, but any other suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=----------032612102926055
```

Try:

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------032612102926055
```

Also instead of

```
POST http://192.168.0.76/SSP.Upload HTTP/1.0
```

you could use relative url:

```
POST /SSP.Upload HTTP/1.0
```

Comment: @Darrin, that seems to have worked in fiddler, now I just need to get it working in the iPhone, which is much more stubborn apparently.

Comment: If you respect [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) even the most stubborn will finally succumb.